# Appium - iOS - Error writing xctestrun file: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4

Tags: ios, xcode, appium

I'm trying to connect Appium 1.12.1 to a physical iOS device with Automatic Server.  These are the capabilities I am trying:

```
{
  "browserName": "Safari",
  "platformName": "iOS",
  "platformVersion": "12.1",
  "deviceName": "iPhone 6",
  "automationName": "XCUITest",
  "startIWDP": true,
  "udid": "auto"
}
```

I am getting a lengthy error that starts with:

```
An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: "xcodebuild failed with code 65 xcodebuild error message: 2019-04-09 10:14:08.626 xcodebuild[22198:212737] Error writing xctestrun file: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The folder “WebDriverAgentRunner_iphoneos12.2-arm64.xctestrun” doesn’t exist."
```

Comment: For ios real device setup, please check [this link](http://appium.io/docs/en/drivers/ios-xcuitest-real-devices/)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
In "/Users/YOUR_NAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/" I have two folders:
WebDriverAgent-akxhdiizyykdxefsthlnfyomlaiz
WebDriverAgent-ciegwgvxzxdrqthilmrmczmqvrgu

And Appium tried take the folder from WebDriverAgent-akxhdiizyykdxefsthlnfyomlaiz but need WebDriverAgent-ciegwgvxzxdrqthilmrmczmqvrgu.
I copied from WebDriverAgent-ciegwgvxzxdrqthilmrmczmqvrgu to WebDriverAgent-akxhdiizyykdxefsthlnfyomlaiz  and now all work good.

Comment: didnt work for me, my problem is that my Build folder doesnt contain a Products folder